# Specific File Size Check with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesize

I would appreciate if someone could help me with following script.  Actually, I am trying to write a batch file that searches for AVI files and check if it is more than 200 MB restrict the file by using cacls or del the same.  I'm new to batch files and I am trying hard to get this done.  Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FILETYPE=*.mp3
SET SIZELIMIT=7,425,794
for /R d:\ %I IN ('%FILETYPE%') do set FILESIZE=%~xI
if %FILESIZE% GTR %SIZELIMIT% ( del %SIZELIMIT% ) ELSE ( echo.file not found )
```

Shad

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
@echo off
set FILETYPE=*.mp3
set SIZELIMIT=7425794
for /r D:\ %i in (%FILETYPE%) do if %~zi gtr %SIZELIMIT% del "%i"
```

Problems with your initial try included:

- commas in `SIZELIMIT` shouldn't have been there
- `if` statement not contained in `for` loop
- `~x` returns file extension; you wanted `~z` for file size
- no need to quote `%FILETYPE%` inside of `in` clause
- should quote `%i` in `del` command in case it contains spaces

Hope this helps.